# How can I ensure Random function does not refresh and present another Form until the First Form presented gets worked by individual?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a function to audit all Chats that were entered using WebApp. WebApp is created using ASP.Net MVC.

The functions works great, and does present a random Chat entered in WebApp last week.

However, the issue I can see is that if an Auditor opens a Chat, but by refreshing the page the previous Chat Audit gets replaced with a new One.

How can I ensure Auditor refreshing or doing any action the same Chat Audit Form stays or gets presented to auditor, and he cannot proceed unless he completes the Audit.

This is my Action Created

```
public ActionResult Feedback()
        {
            var mostRecentMonday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);

            var weekEnd = mostRecentMonday.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1); //will return the end of the day on Sunday

            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                var uName = User.Identity.Name;                
                //int total = db.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatCreateDateTime >= mostRecentMonday && x.ChatCreateDateTime <= weekEnd && x.Feedback == null).ToArray().ToList().Count();

                var result = db.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatCreateDateTime >= mostRecentMonday && x.ChatCreateDateTime <= weekEnd && x.Feedback == null && x.Username != uName).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
                result.Scenarios = new SelectList(db.Scenarios.ToList(), "ScenarioId", "ScenarioList");
                                
                return View(result);
            }
        }
```

Help is very much appreciated

Comment: The  `Random Function` means bakend or front-end?

Comment: Above is the back end code, front end opens a form by randomly selection of chatid

Comment: So the random id is generated by backend?

Comment: Yes, that is true, backend generates the random id